# How to include database without increasing app size?

Tags: android, flutter, sqlite, size

I got an SQLite database of 150 Mb and they want it in the application so a first time user doesn't face downloading after installation from Google Play. Someone suggested with a MacBook this can be done:

> i use the LZMA2 compression method which reduced the entire database's size to **39mb** then just move that compressed file to your flutter app's asset folder, then decompress it using flutter archive package  and then use SQLite to install that database from uncompressed file. whatever you have the file now try decompressing it using flutter archiver

Doing so:

1. Can a user delete the database from his storage?
2. Will decompression increase app size without showing database to the user?
3. If I import it into user's phone storage will cleaner of phone delete this database?
4. Can I use database at runtime after decompression?

I want to use this database in my application without increasing app size (I want to make it 90 Mb). With flutter_archive package I failed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes user can delete it clearing app data as user owns the phone so has these rights.
2. Yes but you need to code that, database won't process itself.
3. It depends where you store the database file, You should put it in `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` location from [Path Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package. Data saved there is only accessible from your app (if they don't use root privilege). Saving database file into public directories like downloads or documents folder is not recommended.
4. Yes you can use it on runtime, you just need to check whether file exists before trying to access.

How you can achieve it:

1. Compress the file. Use zip for example. It's not necessary to use Mac to compress to zip format.
2. Copy compressed database to project's assets folder.
3. On application main function (or data initialization stage) check if you decompressed before connecting to it.
4. If database file is not found, decompress it using [archive](https://pub.dev/packages/archive) plugin.

Comment: FLUTTER ARCHIVER PACKAGE WILL BE USE  OR ONLY ARCHIVE PACKAGE?

Comment: @HSK only archive package is enough